# ScraPy spider crawling but not exporting

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a ScraPy Code that is running in shell, but when I try to export it to csv, it returns an empty file. It exports data when I do not go into a link and try to parse the description, but once I add the extra method of parsing the contents, it fails to work. Here is the code:

```
class MonsterSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "monster"
    allowed_domains = ["jobs.monster.com"]
    base_url = "http://jobs.monster.com/v-technology.aspx?"
    start_urls = [
        "http://jobs.monster.com/v-technology.aspx"
    ]
    for i in range(1,5):
        start_urls.append(base_url + "page=" + str(i))

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("jobs.monster.com",))
         , callback = 'parse_items'),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-12"]')

        #items = []

        for site in sites.xpath('.//article[@class="js_result_row"]'):
            item = MonsterItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('.//span[@itemprop = "title"]/text()').extract()
            item['company'] = site.xpath('.//span[@itemprop = "name"]/text()').extract()
            item['city'] = site.xpath('.//span[@itemprop = "addressLocality"]/text()').extract()
            item['state'] = site.xpath('.//span[@itemprop = "addressRegion"]/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.xpath('.//a[@data-m_impr_a_placement_id= "jsr"]/@href').extract()
            follow = ''.join(item["link"])
            request = Request(follow, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)
            request.meta["item"] =  item
            yield request
            #items.append(item)
            #return items

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]
        item['desc'] = site.xpath('.//div[@itemprop = "description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Taking out the parse_dir_contents and uncommenting the empty "lists" list and "append" code was the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as @tayfun suggests you should use `response.xpath` or define the `site` variable.

By the way, you do not need to use `sel = Selector(response)`. Responses come with the `xpath` function, there is no need to cover it into another selector.

However **the main problem** is that you restrict the domain of the spider. You define `allowed_domains = ["jobs.monster.com"]` however if you look at the URL to `follow` of your custom `Request` you can see that they are something like `http://jobview.monster.com/` or `http://job-openings.monster.com`. In this case your `parse_dir_contents` is not executed (the domain is not allowed) and your `item` does not get returned so you won't get any results.

Change `allowed_domains = ["jobs.monster.com"]` to

```
allowed_domains = ["monster.com"]
```

and you will be fine and your app will work and return items.

Comment: thanks! this created an output, but now the fields are a little jumbled. will have to troubleshoot more to get the correct output, but this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `parse_dir_contents` method:

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    item = response.meta["item"]
    item['desc'] = response.xpath('.//div[@itemprop=description"]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

Note the use of `response`. I don't know where you got `site` that you are currently using from.

Also, try to provide the error details when you post a question. Writing "it fails to work" doesn't say much.

Comment: agree with including error details except that the spider runs fine, but there is no output in the resulting csv file.